# rounding error of implicit and explicit method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, rounding-error

To solve the differential equation $y'=f(t,y), y(0)=y_0$ consider a explicit $y_{n+1}=y_n+hf(t_n,y_n)$ and a implicit $y_{n+1}=y_n+hf(t_{n+1},y_{n+1})$ method to solve the ODE. If in the explicit method we have a rounding error of $\epsilon$ in each step of the iteration, then how large is $\epsilon$ in the implicit method? I think it has to be bigger?

Comment: What is the "rounding error" in the abstract formulation of the method? Do you mean the truncation error? This is not so much truncation of digits, more truncation of Taylor expansions.

Comment: @LutzLehmann yes I mean the truncation error. So I can't say anything about how $\epsilon$ changes with implicit procedures?

Comment: Largely and locally, the two truncation errors just have opposite sign. Globally this can lead to different overall error behavior and stability.